# How to use array subscript operator for passing address of member in structure to `scanf`?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to c.i read that array subscript operator and pointer arithmetic are interchangeable for access member variable.But in the following code i get error when i used the  `->` operator for access the member variable i get error .i am bit confuse what is happening under the hood .what am i missing .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        int x, y;
} Point;

int main ()
{
        int numOf;
        Point *myPoints = NULL;
        FILE *myfile = fopen ("c:\\jobs.txt","r");
        if (myfile == NULL)
            perror ("Error opening file");
        else
        {
            fscanf(myfile, "%d", &numOf);
            myPoints = (Point *)malloc(sizeof(Point) * numOf);
            while ( !feof (myfile) && numOf-- )
            {
               fscanf(myfile, "%d %d", &(myPoints+numOf)->x, &myPoints[numOf].y);// compile and works 
               //fscanf(myfile, "%d %d", &myPoints[numOf]->x, &myPoints[numOf].y);// dos not compile or  &(myPoints[numOf])->x
            }
            printf("%d %d \n",myPoints->x,myPoints->y);//compile and works 
        }
        fclose(myfile);
        //Do stuff with array
        free ((void *)myPoints);
        getchar();//Press enter to close debugger etc.
        return 0;
}
```

is the cases when i use subscript operator i can't use the `->` with it .
like `&myPoints[numOf]->x`

Comment: The arrow `->` binds tighter than the `&` address of, so `&myPoints[numOf]->x` is the same as `&(myPoints[numOf]->x)`, which is invalid because `myPoints[numOf]` is a structure and requires a dot `.`, rather than `(&myPoints[numOf])->x`, which would pass `x` to `fscanf()` or `&(&(myPoints[numOf])->x)` which should pass the address of `x` to `fscanf()`.

Comment: In gcc, It is not showing any error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but why &(mypoints+numOf)->x works as (mypoints+numOf) is same as mypoints[numOf]. i am bit confuse can u explain a bit more

Comment: Remember the star: `*(myPoints+numOf)` is equivalent to `myPoints[numOf]`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  `&(&(myPoints[numOf])->x)` is not working also `main.c:22:51: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'Point')`

Comment: I was a bit worried about that.  It's damn ugly, that's for sure, and should never actually be written.  Let me go experiment with a friendly compiler.

Comment: Incidentally, you should be checking the return value from `fscanf()` and [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: Ugh!  I got caught by the same problem you did, which was a tad careless.  In my defense, I'd never write code like that.  This gruesome expression does compile, though:  `int *ip04 = &(&(myPoints[numOf]))->x;` where I assigned to an `int *` rather than passing the `int *` to `fscanf()`.

Comment: @avi Do not cast the return of `malloc`. e.g. `myPoints = (Point *)malloc(sizeof(Point) * numOf);` should simply be `myPoints = malloc(sizeof(Point) * numOf);` or even simpler `myPoints = malloc( sizeof *myPoints * numOf);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin can you elaborate what would be difference if i not cast to Point .

Comment: There is NO difference. `malloc` returns a void pointer to the start address for the block of memory allocated. It's not `Point` type or any other type, it's just a memory address. When you cast, you introduce the potential for error that is difficult to debug. You don't need the cast, why make your life harder by doing it?

Comment: so why books  cast to specific datatypes @DavidC.Rankin. if there is not advantage of casting

Comment: You will have to ask the ill informed author. Perhaps they were trying to make a point or perhaps it was a limitation on their compiler from **years and years** ago. If you don't want to take my word for it. Search `cast malloc` here on StackOverflow and see what you find...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expression `myPoints + numOf` has type `Point *` that is a pointer. To access a data member of the object pointed to by the pointer there is used the following syntax

```
( myPoints + numOf )->x
```

The address of this data member `x` can be get using unary operator `&`. Thus expression

```
&( myPoints + numOf )->x
```

gives the address of data member `x` of the object pointed to by pointer `myPoints + numOf`.

You could write the above expression like

```
&( *( myPoints + numOf ) ).x
```

Because postfix operator `.` has higher priority than the unary operator `*` you have to use parentheses.

In fact expression `( *( myPoints + numOf ) ).x` is equivalent to expression 
`myPoints[numOf].x`. These two forms give the same result. So instead of

```
&( myPoints + numOf )->x
```

or

```
&( *( myPoints + numOf ) ).x
```

you may write

```
&myPoints[numOf].x
```

This record

```
&myPoints[numOf]->x
```

is invalid because expression `myPoints[numOf]` does not yield a pointer. It is an object of type Point itself.

As the priority of postfix subscript operator [] and of -> is higher than the priority of unary operator & then you have to write instead

```
&( &myPoints[numOf] )->x
```

Comment: for   `(&myPoints[numof])->x` i got segmentation fault

Comment: @avi You have to specify the address &(&myPoints[numof])->x

Comment: can you tell me why using   &(&(myPoints[numOf])->x) not working ..also can u suggest some reading so that i can clear myself more on this matter

Comment: @avi This &(&(myPoints[numOf])->x) does not work because the priority of the postfix operator -> is higher than priority of unary operator &. In fact expression  &(myPoints[numOf])->x is equivalent to &(myPoints[numOf]->x ) while you need ( &myPoints[numOf] )->x